# How to authenticate different type of applications using OAuth and one WebAPI

Tags: c#, wpf, angularjs, azure, oauth-2.0

I have a WPF client application and AngularJs client connecting to the same Web API to get\send data.
I want to apply OAuth with Azure as identity provider.
What I want is to use this single Web API that both of the applications calling, not to create separate APIs for each.

Thanks

Comment: have a look on this http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/ . it is a part of bigger tutorial doing similiar thing you need ... not sure about the WPF, but google could help with that part ...

Comment: It only guide me toward building using AngularJs client only, what I need is to build WPF & AngularJs

Comment: Sure you can do this! However stackoverflow is not suitable for questions "How do I do this?" or "How do I do that?". When you have some code and struggle with it - you are welcome to post question. Until then, you can carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @astaykov you must get this wrong, this is a suitable question here, I'm asking for the way to write a code to do what I need, this is what stackoverflow is all about.
see these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to

Comment: indeed it does not give you an answer, but it's a good starting point and in combination with few searches in search engine of your choice you'll find solution...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,
When you want to authenticate SPA app & WPF and both of them using the same WebAPI you'll face a problem, that in SPA case (see this [sample](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet)), in the server side (WebAPI) in the **Startup.ConfigureAuth** you need to set Audience property same as ClientId, but when you need to apply OAuth with WPF (native client, see this [sample](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet)) you'll need to provide it as "App ID URI".

You solve this by adding the code from the first sample and the code from the second both in your **Startup.ConfigureAuth** method in your project.